# get facebook profile picture for our database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the Facebook profile pictures of our friends and store them in our database for further use. (Like url of their facebook profiles, as if they change their profile pictures we automatically get their new profile picture)
Something similar can be done with the help of graph.facebook.com and facebook api, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Please can I have the code or source or even just little bit of guidance how to do that.
I am using php and mysql and using xampp as my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook API to get the picture:

```
/* make the API call */
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/me/picture"
);
/* handle the result */
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: but how to store the image to database??

Comment: `file_get_contents` followed by `file_put_contents` would work. You would then store the link to the saved profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the profile pictures

Assuming you have the user's username, you can get the profile picture from this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/{username}/picture`

For example, if you wanted my picture, you could grab the image from `https://graph.facebook.com/hawkw/picture`

You could use `file_get_contents` in PHP to retrieve the image.

If you want to get a specific size image, you can use the url `https://graph.facebook.com/{username}/picture?type={size}`, replacing {size} with `square`, `small`, `normal`, or `large`, depending on what size you want. Alternatively, you can specify specific image sizes with `https://graph.facebook.com/{username}/picture?width={width}&height={height}`.

### Storing them in the DB

First, you're gonna want to make a table to store your images. I'll let you figure that out yourself based on the DB schema you're using. The images should be stored as `BLOB`s.

Then you'll want to connect to the DB. Here's some sample code for opening a DB connection:

```
// Make the connect to MySQL or die
// and display an error.
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select your database
mysql_select_db ($database);
```

You should then insert the images into the table using a query that looks something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO images_table ";
$query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
```

And then call

```
$succeeded = mysql_query($query, $img);
```

Note that I'm assigning the results of `mysql_query` to a variable called `$succeeded` because `mysql_query` returns a boolean that you can use to determine if the `INSERT` command succeeded or not - it should be `TRUE` if the image was successfully inserted. This will allow you to respond to errors in the DB insert process.

### References

Please note that I've never actually used PHP (and I don't really ever plan on it) - this is all the result of a few Google searches. I haven't tested any of this code, so it may not work right out of the box, but it should be enough to get you going in the right direction.

[Facebook API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)

[Tutorial: Storing images in MySQL with PHP](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/)

Comment: will this code work to save the image..??
$img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fid.'/picture?type=large');
$file = dirname(__file__).'/avatar/'.$fid.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, $img);

Comment: I don't know PHP very well (or at all), but it doesn't look like that will work if you're trying to put the pictures in a MySQL database - it looks like you're trying to save the pictures as a file rather than store them in the DB.

Comment: @user3168567: I added a section to my answer on how to store the images in your MySQL database - I hope it's helpful!